# LFTP wildcard source folder

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner, lftp

I'm trying to use LFTP in my GitLab continuous integration setup so I can mirror JSON files with my destination. However, I'd like to only mirror on a set of folders using a wildcard, but I cannot seem to get this working.

I tried this mirror command configuration in LFTP, but this results in a "No such file or directory" error. I assume I'm parsing the wildcard wrong somehow.

What I tried: `lftp -c "set sftp:auto-confirm true; open sftp://$DEVELOPMENT_DEPLOY_USER:$DEVELOPMENT_DEPLOY_PASSWORD@$DEVELOPMENT_DEPLOY_HOST:$DEVELOPMENT_DEPLOY_PORT; mirror -Rev ./somefolder_* $DEVELOPMENT_DESTINATION_FOLDER --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude .* --exclude .*/ --include ./*.json"`

Results in:
`/home/gitlab-runner/builds/82ffc821/0/somegroup/someproject/somefolder_*: No such file or directory`

I'm probably  missing something obvious. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Try adding a `-v` to your command right after `lftp` to get more verbose output.

Comment: @StefanvanGastel it doesn't provide any more info in the console. The error remains; no such file or directory.

Comment: Ok, try reducing the command to get the reason for this error. So test with uploading all files before adding wildcards.

Comment: The error is caused by the wildcard I'm trying to use for the source folder. What I'm trying to do is; I have two folders: somefolder_one and somefolder_two. I'm trying to mirror both by specifying somefolder_* in the command, as wildcard, but this doesn't seem to be parsed properly and it tries to load the exact folder somefolder_*, which does not exist. It should pick both folders as source and mirror those two.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe old but find that in [man](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/lftp.1.html#:%7E:text=Include%20and%20exclude,a%20slash%20appended.) :

> Include and exclude options can be specified multiple times. It means
> that a file  or  directory
> would  be  mirrored  if  it matches an include and does not match to excludes after the
> include, or does not match anything and the first check is exclude. Directories  are  matched
> with a slash appended.

So first it will execute "include" argument, lastly "exclude" with is " --exclude .* --exclude .*/". After that glob, no file math to mirror. Use "--verbose" to check what files are touch by lftp